# Segmentation boundaries image in eCognition

Tags: ecognition, image-segmentation

I need to save the segmentation result (boundaries image) as a raster file using eCognition.

Anybody can give me some directions about this?

Comment: Which version are you using? Developer, Essentials or Architect? If it is Developer, add a process and choose "Export Thematic Raster" - from there, change the export type from "Image Objects" to "Classification". This will give you a classified integer raster, where each class in your dataset is a unique number.

Comment: Hi @MikkelLydholmRasmussen. I am working with Developer version. I followed your steps, but I got the classified image. Do you know how can I get the borders image (blue borders) from segmentation result? I try different export options but I cant find the correct one for me. Any other suggestion?. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try using "Export Thematic Layer" - remember to specify the format.

Comment: Hi @MikkelLydholmRasmussen. I could not find how to export only borders as raster image, but you help me to know some other interesting functions. Finally, I decided to copy the raster image with overlapped object borders, and extract borders using other image processing software. Thanks anyway.